# What is the difference between object().func and object.func in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, var, func

I am new to swift and I want to know if there is a difference between geoCoder() :

```
      var geoCoder:CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
      geoCoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(newCoordinate, completionHandler: { (<#[CLPlacemark]?#>, <#NSError?#>) -> Void in
            <#code#>
        })
```

and geroCoder:

```
      var geoCoder:CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
      geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(newCoordinate, completionHandler: { (<#[CLPlacemark]?#>, <#NSError?#>) -> Void in
            <#code#>
        })
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference. The first one won't compile (even if you fill in the placeholders correctly), and the second will.

You can't say `geoCoder()` because `geoCoder` is not a function.

(In C++, we can overload the `()` operator to make things that are not functions act like functions. Swift doesn't allow that, so you can only put `()` after things that are genuinely functions.)

Comment: Thank you for your help Rob. That clears it up for me.